# How to Move Up a Selected Row in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qtableview, qt4.8, qstandarditemmodel

I have a `QTableView` with 3 rows and 2 columns. (Here I am using a `QStandardItemModel`). I want to move up/move down a single row when a QPushButton is clicked. How can I move up/down a row in `QTableView`?

Thanks for your reply vahancho. I have already tried using `QAbstractItemModel::moveRow`, but it doesn't work:

```
   int currentRow = ui->tableView->currentIndex().row();
   QModelIndex sourceParent = ui->tableView->model()->index(ui->tableView->selectionModel()->currentIndex().row(),0);
   QModelIndex destinationParent = ui->tableView->model()->index(ui->tableView->selectionModel()->currentIndex().row()+1,0);
   ui->tableView->model()->moveRow(sourceParent,currentRow, destinationParent,destinationParent.row());
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it is a virtual function you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: neuronet, thank you for your reply. So, are you saying that this function (`moveRow()`) does nothing if you do not implement it yourself? . So what is the idea of this function?

Answer (score 6):

Use Qt documentation for `QStandartItemModel` - [QStandardItemModel Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html)

1. `takeRow`
2. `insertRow`

Comment: i agree, `QStandardItemModel` is more convinient :)

Comment: I posted solution to author, but he deleted my post. Problem was that TS didn't know about type casting and he couldn't cast QModelIndex::model() to QStandartItemModel.

Comment: @SaZ who is TS, what do you mean he deleted the post, he can't do that with such low rep can he?

Comment: TS == topic starter. He posted an answer, and i commented it. So he deleted his answer and my comment became invisible.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Qt5 you can take a look on this function:

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::moveRow(const QModelIndex & sourceParent, int sourceColumn, const QModelIndex & destinationParent, int destinationChild)
```

"On models that support this, moves sourceColumn from sourceParent to destinationChild under destinationParent. Returns true if the columns were successfully moved; otherwise returns false."

Comment: abstractitemmodel, so it means you still need to implement it yourself, right?

Comment: @neuronet, yes. Actually, to make `moveRow()` work, you need to implement `QAbstractItemModel::moveRows()` virtual function.

Comment: It is strange that this virtual function is available but no Qt classes implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short utility I use for moving the Qt::DisplayData of a row in QAbstractItemModel:

```
void CopyRowData( QAbstractItemModel * pModelDst, const QAbstractItemModel * pModelSrc, int nRowDst, int nRowSrc, const QModelIndex &parentDst /*= QModelIndex()*/, const QModelIndex &parentSrc /*= QModelIndex()*/, int nRole /*= Qt::DisplayRole*/ )
{
    if (parentSrc.isValid())
        assert(parentSrc.model() == pModelSrc);
    if (parentDst.isValid())
        assert(parentDst.model() == pModelDst);

    int nCols = pModelSrc->columnCount(parentSrc);

    for (int i = 0; i < nCols ; ++i)
        pModelDst->setData(pModelDst->index(nRowDst, i, parentDst), pModelSrc->index(nRowSrc, i, parentSrc).data(nRole), nRole);
}

bool MoveModelRows( QAbstractItemModel * pModel, int nSrcRow, int nDstRow, int nCount /*= 1*/, const QModelIndex &parent /*= QModelIndex()*/ )
{
    if (nSrcRow < 0 || nSrcRow >= pModel->rowCount(parent) ||
        nDstRow < 0 || nDstRow >= pModel->rowCount(parent))
        return false;

    if (nSrcRow == nDstRow)
        return true;

    int nDstRowNew = nSrcRow > nDstRow ? nDstRow : nDstRow + 1;

    if (!pModel->insertRows(nDstRowNew, nCount, parent))
        return false;

    int nSrcRowNew = nSrcRow > nDstRow ? nSrcRow + nCount : nSrcRow;

    for (int i = 0; i < nCount; ++i)
        CopyRowData(pModel, pModel, nDstRowNew + i, nSrcRowNew + i, parent, parent);

    pModel->removeRows(nSrcRowNew, nCount, parent);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea that SaZ said:

> Use Qt documentation for `QStandartItemModel` - [QStandardItemModel Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html)
>
> 1. `takeRow`
> 2. `insertRow`

This is the code I did for this purpose:

```
QModelIndexList selection = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
int row = selection[0].row();
QList<QStandardItem*> itemList = ui->tableView->model()->takeRow(row);
ui->tableView->model()->insertRow(row-1,itemList);
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think this would help:

```
for(int colId=0;colId<ui->tableWidget->columnCount();++colId)
{
    QTableWidgetItem *item1=new QTableWidgetItem( *ui->tableWidget->item(id_row1,colId) );
    QTableWidgetItem *item2=new QTableWidgetItem( *ui->tableWidget->item(id_row2,colId) );

    ui->tableWidget->setItem(id_row1,colId, item2 );
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(id_row2,colId, item1 );
}
```

Comment: This creates unnecessary copies using somewhat expensive heap allocations.