# Swap QTreeView items on drag and drop operation

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt4, qtreeview

Let's say we have the following hierarchy:

```
+ A
|-- B
  |-- D
|-- C
```

And let's say the user drags C onto B. Is it possible to have both nodes (including children) swapped as the result of that drag and drop operation?

```
+ A
|-- C
|-- B
  |-- D
```

I've tried multiple approaches: from subclassing the item model (`dropMimeData`, `insertRows`, etc) to adjusting modes with `setDragDropOverwriteMode` and `DragDropMode::InternalMove`, to subclassing `dropEvent(QDropEvent * e)` and nothing worked so far.

I've encountered the following techincal limitations:

- `QStandardItemModel::dropMimeData` and `QTreeview::dropEvent` won't let you know the source index, they forward mime data, and there's no way to obtain the source's QModelIndex to perform the swapping.
- The `DragDropMode::InternalMove` and `setDragDropOverwriteMode` approach doesn't work as expected, the source node gets appended to the drop target node somehow, and the source node is removed. If you set `DragDropMode::Copy`, the source node is preserved, but the target node isn't overwritten either.

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've inspect [source code of Qt](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/6248dff2c7f3288d675de639abfbbc6c1d618006:src/gui/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp) and it turns out that to fetch source index you should use current selection. So override `QTreeview::dropEvent` and fetch current selection by calling [selectedIndexes()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#selectedIndexes).

---

Swap is not a problem. You have to just do move twice.
There is spatial method for that: [QAbstractItemModel::moveRow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#moveRow) (in threes you have only one column so moving row is ok).
Here you have a answer with [another solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18694727/1387438) (for standard item model).

If you have own custom model you have to do it directly on your data and just emit proper signals about moving items.

Comment: This works! Although it doesn't answer the question of how to do the actual swapping. I've been trying with `QStandardItemModel::takeItem` and the such but the `QModelIndex`es get corrupted when you try to perform the swap. Not to mention how to deal with the child nodes.

Comment: That's for Qt5 though.

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted your answer since I migrated to Qt5 anyway. That approach causes a crash due to a [bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-18539) in QTreeview though, so I'd recommend migrating.